# How to get all available printer in network

Tags: python-3.9

how do i get all the available printer in the network the user has rights for?
I tried the following code:

```
win32print.EnumPrinters(100, None, 1)
```

But I only got 5 of 20 printer with this line. But for now it is the best result I get.

If I try

```
win32print.EnumPrinters(win32print.PRINTER_ENUM_NETWORK, None, 1)
```

I get the error:

```
pywintypes.error: (16385, 'EnumPrinters', 'No error message is available')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it.
I have to use PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS